# How to specify an item in an object array within an object array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an object array named objects that I've used a loop for to create 5 new object arrays within it.
I print their contents like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Object[]) objects[1]));

returns:
[1, 1, 3]
```

These are the contents of the second array, I would like to only return the 3, how would I do so?

Comment: I'm not following. Show the loop.

Comment: public static void main(String args[]){
        Object[] objects = new Object[5];
        int x = 0;
        do {

            objects[x] = new Object[] {1, 1, 3};
            x++;
        } while (x < 5);

Comment: Edit the question instead

Comment: Without knowing the context, a nested array of Objects sounds like you should rethink the code overall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Object[] tempArr = (Object[]) objects[1];

System.out.println(tempArr[tempArr.Length - 1]);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: It works, I will have to feed all the arrays through the temp one though eventually using another loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: something like this,

```
System.out.println(((Object[]) objects[1])[2]);
```

The expression:

```
((Object[]) objects[1]) => [1,1,3]
```

returns an array, so you can access it via the `[]` operator like so:

```
((Object[]) objects[1])[2] => 3
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah that was because since I accessed the position 2 of the second array it returned a number, not an array so the Arrays.toString() was complaining about it, now I've taken out that part and works fine.

Comment: Remember to keep a set of parenthesis around the Object[] part. It works just as danielR says. Also, your code makes little sense. If you want a 2d array, create a 2d array.